# php stop of statement in form validation

Tags: php, html

i am a beginner and am trying to make a form validation with PHP. i want to check if one of the inputs is empty, the form says that the empty input is required.

I show the php script behind.

```
<?php
        $titleErr = $authorErr = $keywordsErr = $contentErr = "";
        $title = $author = $keywords = $content = "";

        if (empty($_POST["submit"])) {
            if(empty($_POST["title"])){
                $titleErr = "title is required";
            }

            if(empty($_POST["author"])){
                $authorErr = "author name is required";
            }

            if(empty($_POST["keywords"])){
                $keywordsErr = "keywords are required";
            }

            if(empty($_POST["content"])){
                $contentErr = "This field is required";
            }

        }
        ?> 
        <form method="post" action="insert_post.php">
            <table width="600" align="center" border="10">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="yellow" colspan="6"><h1>Insert New Post Here</h1></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Post Title:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="title" size="38">
                        <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $titleErr; ?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Post Author:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" size="38">
                    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $authorErr; ?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Post Keywords:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="keywords" size="38">
                    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $keywordsErr; ?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Post Image:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Post Content</td>
                    <td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>
                    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $contentErr; ?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $date = date('d-m-Y');
        $author = $_POST['author'];
        $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "../images/$image");
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_keywords, post_image, post_content) VALUES('$title', '$date', '$author', '$keywords', '$image', '$content')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if($query){
            echo"<center><h1>Post Published Succesfully!</h1></center>";
        }
    }

?>
```

The problem is i want to stop the scrit if the inputs are empty but i can't use functions like: exit() and break;.
and if i submit, the form sends empty values to the database :C.

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We make use of session variables which temporarily stores data locally. To use sessions we must always start sessions by `session_start()` at the start of every page to be able to access the variables. Now we can store data and pass it to whatever page we want to without having to send it - we just store it and then grab it.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$titleErr = $authorErr = $keywordsErr = $contentErr = "";
$title = $author = $keywords = $content = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["title"])){
        $titleErr = "title is required";
    }

    if(empty($_POST["author"])){
        $authorErr = "author name is required";
    }

    if(empty($_POST["keywords"])){
        $keywordsErr = "keywords are required";
    }

    if(empty($_POST["content"])){
        $contentErr = "This field is required";
    }
    if(!empty($_POST["title"]) && !empty($_POST["author"]) && !empty($_POST["keywords"]) && !empty($_POST["content"])){
        $_SESSION["title"] = $_POST["title"];
        $_SESSION["author"] = $_POST["author"];
        $_SESSION["keywords"] = $_POST["keywords"];
        $_SESSION["content"] = $_POST["content"];
        $_SESSION["image"] = $_FILES["image"];
        header("location: insert_post.php");
        exit();
    }

}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <table width="600" align="center" border="10">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="yellow" colspan="6"><h1>Insert New Post Here</h1></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Title:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" size="38" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])){ echo $_POST['title']; }; ?>">
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $titleErr; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Author:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="author" size="38" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['author'])){echo $_POST['author']; }; ?>">
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $authorErr; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Keywords:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="keywords" size="38" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){echo $_POST['keywords']; }; ?>">
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $keywordsErr; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Content</td>
            <td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['content'])){echo $_POST['content']; }; ?>"></textarea>
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $contentErr; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**insert_post.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

include("includes/connect.php");
$title = $_SESSION['title'];
$author = $_SESSION['author'];
$keywords = $_SESSION['keywords'];
$content = $_SESSION['content'];

$date = date('d-m-Y');
$image = $_SESSION['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_SESSION['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "../images/$image");
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_keywords, post_image, post_content) VALUES('$title', '$date', '$author', '$keywords', '$image', '$content')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($query){
    echo"<center><h1>Post Published Succesfully!</h1></center>";
}
else{
    echo "<center><h1>Error! Post was not published!</h1></center>";
}

echo $title . " " . $author . " " . $keywords . " " . $content;

?>
```

Btw, you should be using prepared statements for your database inserts to prevent SQL-injections. Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: It doesn't work well... It is already showing warnings. it is the meaning that the warning must come if you press on the submit button while the input(s) are empty.

Comment: Well then you can use jQuerys validation. You cannot use PHP for this as it's a server side language. jQuery, which is a JavaScript library, works client side (also does JavaScript). Read more about jQuery validation here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: I believe that this can be done without jQuery. This form is just like the example in W3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_special. The form keeps sending values to the database, even if the form is empty.(my form)

Comment: Well in the example the form is submitting to the same page, I thought you wanted to send the data to another page? Anyway this can be done either way. But I have to know how you want it.

Comment: I want my form to work in the same way as the example from w3schools. if all inputs of my form are filled and press submit, the form must insert the values into the database.if the input(s) are empty, the fomr must give warning(s) and must not insert values into the database.

Comment: Ok see my latest edit. It should work the way you want it to work.

Comment: It works but there are still a few problems :s. There are errors in the top 3 inputs of index.php, like: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: title in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\index.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />. If i send an empty form, i see only one error (error variable of the content field). the top 3 inputs doesn't show errors.

Comment: If i submit a filled form i see this error: Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\index.php on line 27. What does this mean? i can't fix it.

Comment: IT WORKS but it inserts empty values even if the form is filled. because they are undefined. i don't know why. this are the errors: Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: author in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: keywords in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: content in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 10

Comment: Working fine over here, no errors. Have you copied all of the code? Try again.

Comment: oh it works better but it inserts empty values into the database. even if the form is filled. I see only 2 error: Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\admin\insert_post.php on line 12. i really don't understand why it inserts empty values..

Comment: Well do you also want the file upload to be required? If not - you're inserting `$image` into the database which can be empty.

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it working :) Session variables are really handy when sending data in between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Chenge these lines:

```
include("includes/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

to

```
include("includes/connect.php");
if( isset($_POST['submit']) //Fix here, it will only insert if all error message
     && empty($titleErr)    //are empty.
     && empty($authorErr)
     && empty($keywordsErr)
     && empty($contentErr) ){
```

**Edit**

And also change this line

```
if (empty($_POST["submit"])) {
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

On the init of your script. The empty function will return true if you did not submit the page, that's why you are hving the error messages.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if i don't submit, the form says that the input is required. If the form can't send the values to the db.

Comment: @FFBbodie I've edited my answer. Realize that you also where not checking the submit before set the errors variables.

Comment: It works fine but the problem is still not solved. Sending an empty form gives error variables as intended but the problem is, the form still inserts empty value(s) into the database. How can i solve this?

Comment: Ooops, my mistake. I will fix the problem with the logic that I provided you. Realize that I give you the wrong tests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't hAve to Break the Script using the Exit Funktion. Just prove if the error variables aren't empty and only in the Case when they aren't empty send a dB-request.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean exactly. I forgot to tell that i am a beginner. I have to show an error if the inputs are empty. if they arent empty the text won't come.